# "Debugging resource string are unavaible" in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

[Async_ExceptionOccurred]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem
system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.raiseexceptionifnecessary

I'm trying to show the data on the grid to the user by selecting the options from the combobox.The values are complete form and incomplete form.Whenever i select incomplete form it works bt at the other time when i select complete form option i get this exception.Earlier i was having similar problem with incomplete form option.For more information, i am trying to access something around 3 thousand and above data from database and in future it can be 25 thousand also.I think the problem is with the size of the data, but i have set all the timeout values in web.config and clientconfig files.Please somebody help me working on this from last 1 week bt not able to configure it.